# A geometric construction related to an equidistributed sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, logarithms

*Context: I was reading a book when I encountered the following geometric construction in a chapter about equidistributed sequence.*

Let's construct a series of $N$ points $A_1,\ldots,A_N$ of the plane, where $A_n$ has coordinates

$$\left(\mathrm{Re}\left(\sum_{k\leqslant n} e^{2\sqrt 2 i \pi k\log k}\right),\mathrm{Im}\left(\sum_{k\leqslant n} e^{2\sqrt 2 i \pi k\log k}\right)\right).$$

Then let's drawn the lignes $[A_n,A_{n+1}]$ for all $n\in\{1,\ldots,N-1\}$.

Here is what it looks for $N=200$, $N=1500$, $N=10^4$ and $N=10^5$ respectively.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

My questions are the following.

> - What is it behaving like this? What causes those spirals?
> - Can we predict the coordinates of the center of each spiral?
> - Can we predict for which value of $n$ $A_n$ will be at the center of a spiral?

Comment: I understand these curlicue spirals but am unable to replicate these particular examples. There are two problems: (1) $i$ is used in the context of the imaginary number (must be for the spirals) and also as the index for the sequence, and more significantly, (2) you indicate a summation over $k$ but there is no $k$ in the summand, and I'm assuming you intend that $n$ is a constant, I get wonderful spiral with $n$ as the (variable) index for the summation. But they are not the same as yours.

Comment: @CyeWaldman You are right, I made several confusions in all the index, I will fix this. If you want, you can share your code and/or your spirals so we can see why there is a difference.

Comment: If we draw just dots $A_n$, it looks like that they try to avoid the spiral centers,
leaving empty circles of similar (the same?) radius.

Answer (score 3):

I have had a number of experiences with these curlicue spirals, both by accident and by design. These are artifacts that accrue when a spiral equation is undersampled. But let's start at the beginning. Any curve in the complex plane can be expressed in terms of the arc length, $s$ by the equation

$$z=\int e^{i\int \kappa(s)ds}ds$$

where $\kappa(s)$ is the curvature. This equation is derived from the *natural* (or intrinsic) equation, which is independent of any coordinate system. For example, the relation between curvature and tangent angle, $\kappa(s)=d\theta/ds$, is a natural equation.

In your case we would idealize the spiral to the form

$$z(S)=\int_1^S e^{i2\sqrt{2}\pi s\ln s}ds$$

where we notice that we've taken the lower limit from $s=1$ to avoid problems with the logarithm, as well as to be consistent with your summation. A plot of $z(S)$ is shown in the first figure below and is seen the be similar to the right-hand-side of the Cornu/Euler spiral. Not surprising, because in that case you have $s\ln s \Rightarrow s^2$. As $S$ increases, the spiral is filled in with increasingly smaller loops.

However, excess curlicues can arise due to undersampling $s$ in the integral. What happens is that there are sudden changes in the integrand due to rapid changes in the sign of the sine/cosine terms, which throw the value of $z(S)$ out of the nominal spiral. It continues with another spiral until it is thrown off elsewhere.

In the limit of undersampling where $ds=1$, the result is identical with the summation in the OP, that is,

$$z(S)=\int_1^S e^{i2\sqrt{2}\pi s\ln s}ds=\sum_{k=1}^ne^{i2\sqrt{2}\pi k\ln k}=A_n$$

where $n=S$, of course. My results for $n=200,1500,10^4,10^5$ are shown in the second figure below. Since these are not in agreement with yours, I will tell you that these were calculated and plotted in the complex plane using Matlab and, in particular, using the the *cumsum* function, (i.e., cumulative summation). Notice that each image is a subset of the ones of lager values of $n$. In addition, these have been rotated by$-\pi/2$ for presentation purposes.

As to the question of predicting the centers of the spirals, I believe that it is highly unlikely. I cannot even determine that for the *complete* spiral because I cannot get a closed form solution to the integral. Moreover, I can't even get a numerical solution to the infinite integral (having tried WolframAlpha and Mathematica).

Finally, let me draw you attention to another to another post involving curlicue spirals where I also left an answer, [Plotting exponential partial sums in the complex plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1144248/plotting-exponential-partial-sums-in-the-complex-plane).
[image: Continuous spiral]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Very interesting perspectives :) I will try to understand why we don't obtain the same results. I drew my spirals using SageMath.

Comment: To make it clear, I calculate the values of $A_n$ and then plot it as a sequence of points. You were saying something about lines $[An,An+1]$. I don't know if that's the same. BTW, on a personal note, I am a *stagiere anciene* of ONERA (all of 1969). I was there on a postdoctoral  fellowship from the National Science Foundation (US). Thanks for the votes!